# Beacons Notifications not showing after dismissed

Tags: beacon, eddystone, google-nearby, eddystone-url

Im using Nearby and Eddystone URL to broadcast notifications to Chrome on mobile.  After provisioning and setting up of the beacons, it works great.  The notifications shows up in the notification drawer.  However, if it was dismissed by accident or intentionally, it doesn't show up anymore.  I read somewhere that it goes "silent" for some time to avoid pestering the users.  But in my case, it never returned unless I provision the beacons again.

Two questions:

1. Is this a known bug?
2. Will the notification ever return without doing extra work?
3. How to reset it to see the notifications again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the notification has been dismissed on a device recently, that device may not show another notification a period of time. You can reset the backoff policy by opening Settings … Google … Nearby. [Read this and more troubleshooting Tips](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/troubleshooting-eddystone-url-on-android/).

There's nothing you can do about this as it's controlled by Google/Android.

Comment: I cant find the reset.  Im using a Nexus 5x.  How long is that "period of time?" It has been weeks since I last saw my notifications.

Comment: The period of time isn't defined anywhere by google. I wouldn't expect it to be weeks though. More like hours or days. If it's weeks then it's likely something else is wrong like the URL shortener is too slow, the link has become invalid for some reason, you don't have Internet connectivity when you tried etc

Comment: Url shortener it bitly.  I checked the Nearby icon in the drawer and refreshed, I see the links